# two websockets in one python program. one listening. one sending. both on different ports

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

i thought it may be a simple task. and maybe it is for someone who is more experienced in sockets and threading.. i hope you can help me.

the problem is as follows.
[in python]

if have one websocket server (Server A) that transmits messages to its subscribers (Server B) on a port (X). the subscribers listen on that port (X) and pass the messages to its clients over a different port (Y). the subscribers can have multiple clients.

The server A was no problem. The clients were easy too. But now i need to implement the subscriber server.

It has to listen on port X and to send on port Y to its clients. and i have no idea how to do that with websockets..

Do you?

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? What errors are you running into?

Comment: How is this different than the code for the clients? Isn't server B acting as a client in one relationship and as a server on the other? If you wrote server  A and the client, server B should be no more then both modules in a single program.